# Спец.символ из файла

Tags: python

Вопрос с спец.символами в python. Как заставить работать "\n"? В файле есть текст. В тексте в произвольном месте есть символ "\n". Когда достаёшь из файла строку он полностью выводит текст, учитывая стандартные переводы строк, но не то что нужно. Есть ли решение? Если можно обойтись без регулярок, то пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.replace("\\n", "\n")` например. Возможно, есть более элегантное решение...

Comment: Точно! вполне подойдёт. спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Talisman пожалуйста. Аналогичным образом можно другие последовательности заменить если нужно...

Comment: @Talisman это лечит только симптомы, вероятно не устраняя корневую причину. Исправьте лучше код, который генерирует файл.

Comment: @jfs не всегда такое возможно столь же малой кровью...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов за использование "малой крови" типа: `str([1,2,3]).replace("[]", "")` следует лишать commit привилегии.